# Getting specific Data with an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have an API that I want to read certain data from, it works for most of the data but not for one. Namely, the part that I show below, I have to navigate to the "mmr" and there it fails from the number, the season. Maybe someone can help me, I have here the program code and the part which gets the API, in addition I link the API once. Thanks in advance!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/r6api.js/v/1.6.0#typescript-integrations-1

```
const id = await r6api.getId(platform, username).then(el => el[0].userId);
const rank = await r6api.getRank(platform, id, { regions: ['euw'] }).then(el => el[0]);
console.log(`${username} has  ${rank.seasons.number['-1'].id} mmr.`);
```

And the result of the API for the getRank

```
[
  {
    id: '0b95544b-0228-49a7-b338-6d15cfbc3d6a',
    seasons: {
      '16': {
        id: 16,
        name: 'Shifting Tides',
        regions: {
          emea: {
            region: 'emea',
            skillMean: 30.663307433,
            skillStdev: 7.5624420961,
            current: {
              name: 'Unranked',
              id: 0,
              mmr: 3066,
              image: 'https://i.imgur.com/bvnVUEm.png'
            },
            max: {
              name: 'Unranked',
              id: 0,
              mmr: 0,
              image: 'https://i.imgur.com/bvnVUEm.png'
            },
            lastMatch: { mmrChange: 0, won: false, skillStdevChange: -0.0048172252 },
            previousMmr: 0,
            nextMmr: 0,
            topRankPosition: 0,
            kills: 0,
            deaths: 0,
            wins: 0,
            losses: 0,
            matches: 0,
            abandons: 0,
            updateTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  That API wrapper clearly defines `getRank` method with the options for supplying the season, and shows an example call for that method.  What problem are you encountering in your code?

Comment: Hey, thank you for you answer! My Problem is, that i dont know how to get this pecific information of the MMR. if i use the getRank, i get the hole informations. Sorry i am a beginner with JavaScript :)

Comment: please update your question with your code segment that demonstrates what you're attempting to do and explain at what part in your code you're encountering the problem of "getting the whole information".  Also show us a sample of what you mean by "the whole information"

Comment: Now is the code at the end :) The example of the websited worked but this is not working, i dont know what i did wrong..

Answer (score 1):

If its the MMR alone you want I made this ridiculous method that works, it currently just returns the MMR but you can sort of figure it out:

```
const id = await r6api.getId("uplay", "username").then(el => el[0].userId);
const rank = await r6api.getRank("uplay", id, { regions: ['euw'] }).then(el => el[0]);
const info = Object.values(Object.values(Object.values((Object.values(rank))[1])[0])[4])[0]
console.log(info.max.mmr)
```